# What is the TypeScript equivalent of the Closure Compiler type !Object<string, MyClass>?

Tags: typescript, google-closure-compiler

In the [Closure Compiler type system](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System), `!Object<string, !MyClass>` (or equivalently just `!Object<!MyClass>`) is a type of a value which is a (non-null) Object used as a dictionary, having arbitrary strings as keys and (non-null) instances of MyClass as values.  (Note that if `myDict` is of this type then `myDict[str]` might be `undefined`, but `str in myDict` implies `myDict[str] instanceof MyClass`.)

How do I express the same type in the Typescript type system?

Is there any way to additionally specify that the prototype of such an dictionary object must be null (i.e. produced by `Object.create(null)`?  (AFIAK the closure type system does not provide a way to specify this.)

Comment: `Record<string, MyClass>` should work

Comment: Under `"strict": true`, that type is written `{[key: string]: MyClass}`.

Answer (score 2):

> `!Object<string, !MyClass>` (or equivalently just `!Object<!MyClass>`) is a type of a value which is a (non-null) Object used as a dictionary, having arbitrary strings as keys and (non-null) instances of MyClass as values.

This would be the [`Record<Keys, Type>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
const myDict: Record<string, MyClass> = {};
```

This is a ready-made shorthand for [an index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures). This would be the equivalent:

```
const myDict: { [key: string]: MyClass } = {};
```

In order to make sure nothing is `null`, you also need to enable the [`strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) (it's also included in [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)). This will remove `null` as a possible value anywhere *unless* it's explicitly mentioned, e.g., `MyClass | null` would allow `nulls` but `MyClass` by itself will not.

> Is there any way to additionally specify that the prototype of such an dictionary object must be null

No, it's not possible. TypeScript does not differentiate between what was used as prototype. It only does structural matching for type equality, so `Object.create(null)` and `{}` are equivalent in that they are just objects. The type system will not check which was used to create a given object as long as it seems to match the interface.